# Replacing Unicode non-breakable spaces by normal spaces

Tags: xetex, fontspec, luatex, unicode, unicode-math

I am using the Neo keyboard layout, which uses all kinds of modifier keys to input all kinds of characters (e.g. Greek letters and mathematical symbols). It also has shift+Mod3+space mapped to Unicode 0A, no-break space. From time to time it happens that I mistakenly press these buttons (while entering a space between other symbols with the same modifier keys).

Unfortunately [Lua|Xe]TeX obeys these spaces as unbreakable spaces both in normal text and in mathmode (using `fontspec` and `unicode-math`). However my editor (vim) shows the symbol like a normal space, so it is impossible to see where I made a mistake.

Is there an easy way to tell [Lua|Xe]TeX to treat no-break spaces like normal spaces?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ }{ }
```

In the first argument you put a NO-BREAK SPACE (U+00A0), in the second a normal space. A better definition would be

```
\newunicodechar{ }{~}
```

(again the space is NO-BREAK SPACE), so this unbreakable space will stretch or shrink wit the other spaces in the line. Of course use the first one if you want a normal space, *ça va sans dire*. :)

Answer (score 8):

Another solution will be to change vim setup so that you can see the non-breakable space.

```
set listchars=nbsp:¬
set list
```

You can set appropriate syntax highlighting for `NonText` to highlight the non-breakable space.

Comment: Great. Though I'll use ␣, as it has less chance of being actually used in the (math) text.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you might want to use an actual no-break space. So turning them into normal spaces altogether might not be the best idea. In that case Adityas solution is a good start. But I don’t like my indentation displayed as `^I`.

The following colours the no-break spaces in *gvim*:

```
hi NoBreakSpace guibg=LightGoldenrod1 guifg=black
syn match NoBreakSpace / / containedin=ALL
syn match NoBreakSpace / / containedin=ALL
```

You can also do something similar to `set list` by using the conceal feature and replace the displayed character in normal mode with

```
hi Conceal guibg=LightGoldenrod1 guifg=black
syn match WhiteSpace / / containedin=ALL conceal cchar=⍽
syn match WhiteSpace / / containedin=ALL conceal cchar=¦
setl conceallevel=2 concealcursor=nv
```

in *.vim/after/ftplugin/tex/<somename>.vim*.

This will also display `$\alpha^{+1}$` as `α⁺¹`. If you don’t like these other concealments you can disable them with

```
let g:tex_conceal = ""
```

in your *.vimrc*. Compare `:help tex-conceal`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the following:

Go into **Command mode** in vim by hitting `ESC`, so what you enter appears in a special command-line at the bottom of the screen.

**Search:**

Enter `/` directly followed by what you want to search for and hit enter to search in forward direction.

To search in backwards direction, use `?` instead of `/`.

To repeat the search in forward direction just hit `n` and to repeat the search in backwards direction, hit `N`.

To have the searchresults highlighted use `:set hls` (*high-light search*) or add `set hls` to your `vimrc` to switch it on permanently.

**Substitute:**

Again in **command mode** the syntax is: `:[where] s/Searchpattern/Substitution/[Flags]`

`:22,150 s/a/z/ c` this substitutes (the first appearance of) `a` with `z` from line `22` to `150` and the `c` at the end means, that vim will ask you each time before applying the substitution.

`:1,$ s/a/z/ a` will make the same substitution from the first to the last line of the document and the `a` at the end means to substitute without asking.

`:% s/a/z/ g` `%` is a shortcut for `1,$` and `g` means that vim will apply the substitution *globally* — substitute all appearances it finds in a line, else it might only substitute the first appearance.

*These `regular expressions` are utterly powerful.*

**To find out more about this** try `:help substitute` (you can leave the help via `:q`).

---

**`:set hls`**

**`:%s/ / /gc`**