# Lualatex and UTF-8 NonBreaking space

Tags: symbols, unicode

I'm using `Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022/TeX Live for SUSE Linux)` and need to use UTF-8 character `U+00A0` as non breaking space. I found a solution with the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44803/48642).

I know that lualatex uses UTF-8 as input encoding. Therefore is that kind of mapping still required or can I rely on the internal mechanism of lualatex?

Comment: why don't you try it out? set \textwidth=1cm and then type a bit.

Answer (score 1):

By default the character U+00A0 is a catcode 12 punctuation character with no special behaviours, so it acts like `.` it doesn't add a line break point but its appearance depends on the font and it has a fixed font dependent width and unlike a normal space, or active `~`, is not replaced by TeX stretchy glue.

[image]

shows some contexts where space, U+00A0 and `~` act differently. You will see `~` acts like space apart from not allowing line breaks, U+00A0 is completely different.

Comment: If I understand you correctly than the `U+00A0` should NOT prevent any kind of line breaks? I'm confused... Because what you write is that it won't `add a line break point` but that's exactly what a "NON breaking space" should be used for - i.e. parts are glued together (Or not?). But I'm confused if my sample is a valid one - namely usage with `%` which wouldn't cause additional line breaks anyway. Using the `~` produces proportional space distribution while `U+00A0` a fixed width (as you've mentioned).

Comment: @LeO not allowing a linebreak is only part of what a nonbreaking space should to. `.`would do that. The other part is that it should act like a space when there is no liebreaking. U+00A0 does not do that by default.  `~` does. So you can make `^^^^00a0` active and `\let` it to `~`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ulrike I come up with the following example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,english]{article}
\begin{document}
\fbox{  
    \parbox{2cm}{We have 10 \% rest ammount} % encoded UTF-8 character U+A00
}
\fbox{  
    \parbox{2cm}{We have 10 \% rest ammount}
}
\fbox{  
    \parbox{2cm}{We have 10~\% rest ammount}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Conclusion: With lualatex one doesn't need any longer the encoding with `\newunicodechar`.

Comment: there are no U+00A0 in this answer,  just normal spaces `https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html?\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,english]{article}%0A\begin{document}%0A\fbox{%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20\parbox{2cm}{We%20have%2010%20\%25%20rest%20ammount}%20%25%20encoded%20UTF-8%20character%20U+A00%0A}%0A\fbox{%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20\parbox{2cm}{We%20have%2010%20\%25%20rest%20ammount}%0A}%0A\fbox{%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20\parbox{2cm}{We%20have%2010~\%25%20rest%20ammount}%0A}%0A\end{document}`

Comment: If you use A0 characters, `We have 10 \% rest ammount` you get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaysf.png)

Comment: First of all I've update the answer specifically with `U+00A0` (Copied from https://unicode-explorer.com/c/00a0). After the update its still a regular space - therefore don't know if its TexOverflow, my browser or ??? I've uploaded my files to https://file.io/mL2TI8sq2Cmu and wonder how its possible to have two different results.

Comment: ah my comment has a space as well so this site is converting it, but the output you show above is from a normal space, as you can se you get a line break from the _space_ between `have` and `10` in the first for example

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: One last bit for clarification: When I have an `U+00A0` character than this is encoded as character with fixed width. When I now copy paste from the PDF file than I get only a regular space `U+0020`. Is this due to the PDF viewer, to the OS for clipboard or is it mapped as "regular space" (by `lualatex`)? (I don't think the last option is the valid one after following your explanations, but...)

Comment: err... I _think_ it is your viewer doing that (You could check by generating uncompressed pdf for a small example and checking the string in the pdf)