# Print en dash instead of em dash

Tags: punctuation

Is there any way to automatically print en dashes whenever an em dash (the UTF character, **not** threes dashes ---) is used?

Comment: Sure, you can redefine the char (assuming pdflatex + inputenc) . Search for newunicodechar.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't find this

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Replacing Unicode non-breakable spaces by normal spaces](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18368/5764) (different request, same procedure)