# Is there difference between using ‘~’ and Unicode non-breaking space?

Tags: unicode, tilde

Does (Lua)LaTeX treat these two character the same or is there some difference? I've got used to write Unicode NBSPs using Shift-Space shortcut and it is easier for me to use this instead of the tilde character. Should I [change behavior of non-breaking space characters (U+00a0)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18368), or is it redundant?

Comment: with pdflatex (and a current latex) both give `\nobreakspace`. lualatex only inserts the char. But you could redefine it with the \newunicodechar. Personally I prefer the tilde, it is more visible.

Comment: The tilde is (for me) too much visible in Czech-language text where it occurs quite frequently in text. I use `~` in non-natural-language text and U+00a0 in text (which is highlighted by the text editor).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131154/discussion-on-question-by-jiwopene-is-there-difference-between-using--and-uni).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PDFLaTeX and the `latex` command on modern distributions, they are the same.  Both evaluate to `\nobreakspace`.  In LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX, they are different by default, but you can change that.

The `inputenc` package parses the no-break space character (in each encoding that has it) as `\nobreakspace`.  In the Latin-1 encoding, for example, the definition is

```
\DeclareInputText{160}{\nobreakspace}
```

And for the default, UTF-8, it is

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{\nobreakspace}
```

The LaTeX kernel also makes `~` an active character, defined as

```
\def~{\nobreakspace{}}
```

In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, `~` still evaluates to `\nobreakspace`, which is defined in the LaTeX kernel as

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\nobreakspace}{%
   \leavevmode\nobreak\ }
```

However, the character U+00A0 is interpreted literally.  (Although it still searches and copies from the PDF as a space character.) You can clearly see the difference with the test file

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
foo~bar{^^a0}baz
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern sample]

In particular, U+00A0 is a fixed width set by the font, and `\nobreakspace` uses the same interword spacing as the rest of the line—so you might want the fixed-width non-breaking space for a monospace font.  The no-break space character, `^^a0`, `\symbol{"A0}` and `\char"A0` all give the same output.

However, you could redefine U+00A0 to evaluate to `\nobreakspace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{^^a0}{\nobreakspace}

\begin{document}
foo~bar{^^a0}baz
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern sample]

Answer (score 1):

They're different in LuaLaTeX. Look at this example where the spaces preceding “here” are U+00A0.

In the first paragraph the active U+00A0 becomes the normal U+00A0 (of course one doesn't want to use `\newunicodechar` for this setting, but it was necessary for the test). In the second paragraph the active U+00A0 is `\nobreakspace`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\def\testchar{ }% U+00A0
\newunicodechar{ }{\test}% U+00A0

\begin{document}

\let\test\testchar

Some text with nonbreaking space up to here; now spaces are normal and we go to the next line

\let\test\nobreakspace

Some text with nonbreaking space up to here; now spaces are normal and we go to the next line

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, in the first paragraph the interword spaces are not uniform and the ones specified as U+00A0 are bigger.

If you do

```
\newunicodechar{ }{\nobreakspace}% U+00A0
```

in your preamble, you are effectively changing U+00A0 into `\nobreakspace` (that's essentially the same as `~`).